# Airflow Worker - Warm Shutdown

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, celery-task

I have a managed airflow cluster using cloud composer-1.17.6-airflow-2.0.2. The cluster is fairly small (4 worker pods, 1 scheduler pod) and has auto-scaling enabled.

However, I am experiencing airflow worker restarts very frequently even though only few jobs are running.

This is the message I saw before a restart happens on the worker pods using kubectl logs --previous

```
worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)
```

Any idea what could be causing it? I tried setting `celery acks_late` to True and `celery worker_max_tasks_per_child` to 500, however, the issue still persist.

thank you in advance.

Comment: This might be happening most likely due to an out of memory condition. Can you check and confirm whether there has been high CPU usage and Memory usage for the  Composer Nodes. Also let me know if this is not the case.

Comment: @SayanBhattacharya I kind of doubt its because of the memory. There is actually a notification that the cluster is under utilized. Also, even if no jobs are running it still happens. 

actually even if the worker is freshly booted and nothing is running inside, it will occasionally get `Warm shutdown` error.

Comment: Do you have a bunch of scheduled tasks, but none of them are running or done? There is a liveness prober that checks if the workers are able to continuously complete their tasks, and since it sees that it has scheduled tasks but not making any progress on them it kills and restarts the worker (warm shutdown) to try to get it to a healthy state. Also check whether your worker pods are getting evicted or not . You can check by going -> `Kubernates Engine->Workloads->Click on your workload ->look for pods that don't have a green checkmark or are listed as "Evicted"`

Comment: hi @SayanBhattacharya, yes, when I `kubectl describe` the pod there seems to be tasks stuck in queued or scheduled status. hence, the script inside the pod for liveness probe check is triggered. `/var/local/worker_checker.py`. Could this still be because of the memory issue? also I've checked the workloads, all of them is fine except for `airflow-database-init-job` which eventually succeeded on the newly spawned pod.

Comment: Hi @Jay  It seems like it. "Warm shutdown" messages usually indicates resource-intensive DAGs running inside the workers which could exhaust the cluster's resources 
 or tasks failing due to errors inside the DAG code and the composer environment restarting the pods.  And then there is also a liveness checker which will mark the containers unhealthy if they fail a specified check a few times.
I will post an answer mentioning all the possibilities and how you can check them shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone encountering this issue, I've resolved this a couple of months ago by basically refactoring my dynamic DAG. This happens during the parsing of the DAG, which happens on cyclic, I had a couple of logic needed to construct the dag that basically performs backend calls (calling to BigQuery API, calling Xcom backend etc).

As a practice, heavy operations (like external calls) should be avoided when constructing the DAG logic.

I refactored the logic and removed those and the dag parsing improved exponentially from parsing 150 DAGs in 150 seconds to parsing 150 DAGs in 3 seconds. The worker restart never occurred again since.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments `Warm shutdown` messages usually indicates `resource-intensive DAGs` running inside the workers which could `exhaust` the cluster's `resources like CPU or memory` and kubernetes `evicting the pods`, or `tasks failing due to errors` inside the DAG code and the composer environment restarting the pods.

You need to check your `airflow-worker` pods to see whether they are continuously getting evicted or not. To check :

1. open Kubernetes Engine, and then click on Workloads
2. filter by cluster name (you can get this from the Composer environment page). Syntax: cluster:my-composer-cluster-name
3. click on a workload, such as airflow-worker
4. look for pods that don't have a green checkmark or are listed as "Evicted"

`High memory pressure` in any of the GKE nodes will lead the `Kubernetes scheduler to evict pods` from nodes in an attempt `to relieve that pressure.`
There is a `liveness prober` that checks if the workers are able to continuously complete their tasks, and since it sees that it has `scheduled tasks` but not making any progress on them it `kills and restarts` the worker (warm shutdown) to try to get it to a healthy state.
While many different Airflow components are running within GKE, most don't tend to use much memory, so the case that happens most frequently is that we upload a resource-intensive DAG. The Airflow workers run those DAGs, run out of resources, and then get evicted.

You can also look out for whether there are `more than 1 worker running on the same pod`.Again this usually happens as the workers can become co-located on the same node as a result of resource pressure.

### **There are three things you can do in this case:**

- [Manually upgrade the machine types](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/updating#upgrading_the_machine_type) from current ones.
- Create a new Composer environment with a larger machine type (with more memory).
- You try to look through your DAGs and see if they contain resource-intensive, high-memory usage tasks. The DAG files are not supposed to be used for resource intensive-tasks, they should be used for orchestration only.

> I would suggest you to move your DAGs out of the composer environment and see if the workers stop continuously restarting. If they do stop restarting,add the DAGs one-by-one and monitor if the pods restart then identify which one is causing the problem.